# Passive voice in cases when principal clause is followed by noun clause

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

> Active: People say that he lives abroad now.
>   Passive1: It is said (by people) that he lives abroad now.
>   Passive2: He is said to live abroad now.
>
> Active: We understand that he dislikes children.
>   Passive1: It is understood (by us) that he dislikes children.
>   Passive2: He is understood to dislike children.

In the above cases where a principal clause is followed by noun clause, the passive voice  can be formed in the above two ways. I noted that in the first way the change is made only to principal clause and not the noun clause.

But then in a test I came across a question:

> Active: We hope that we shall win the match.
>   Passive (my ans) : It is hoped (by us) that we shall win the match.
>   Passive (correct answer): It is hoped that the match will be won by us.

When to make changes to only the principal clause and when to both?

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolute rule that governs *when* you should use the *it* version and when not. In my opinion (I speak American English), the *it* version is the more conversational of the two:

> They say he doesn't like children. <sup>colloquial</sup>
>
> People say he doesn't like children. <sup>conversational</sup>
>
> It's said he doesn't like children.  <sup>slightly circumspect conversational</sup>
>
> He is said to dislike children.  <sup>educated register conversational verging on stilted</sup>

Again, to my American English ear:

> We understand he lives abroad. <sup>neutral</sup>
>
> It is understood he lives abroad. <sup>formal</sup>
>
> He is understood to live abroad. <sup>stilted</sup>

Answer (score 0):

when Noun clause has an object we change that too to passive voice.

Comment: Can you edit this to expand on what you mean as it is very brief and may not help the OP.